# Formatting date and time

Tags: java, date, string-formatting

I have a question related to conversion/formatting of date.

I have a date,say,workDate with a value, eg: 2011-11-27 00:00:00 
From an input textbox, I receive a time value(as String) in the form "HH:mm:ss", eg: "06:00:00"

My task is to create a new Date,say,newWorkDate, having the same year,month,date as workDate,and time to be the textbox input value.

So in this case, newWorkDate should be equal to 2011-11-27 06:00:00.
Can you help me figure out how this can be achieved using Java?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    //Text box input is converted to Date format -what will be the default year,month and date set here?
     Date textBoxTime = df.parse(minorMandatoryShiftStartTimeStr);

     Date workDate = getWorkDate();
     int year = Integer.parseInt(DateHelper.getYYYYMMDD(workDate).substring(0, 4));
     int month = Integer.parseInt(DateHelper.getYYYYMMDD(workDate).substring(4, 6));
     int date = Integer.parseInt(DateHelper.getYYYYMMDD(workDate).substring(6, 8));

     Date newWorkDate = DateHelper.createDate(year, month, day);
    //not sure how to set the textBox time to this newWorkDate.

[UPDATE]: Thx for the help,guys!Here is the updated code based on all your suggestions..Hopefully this will work.:)

 String[] split = textBoxTime.split(":");
             int hour = 0;
               if (!split[0].isEmpty)){ 
               hour = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);}
             int minute = 0;
             if (!split[1].isEmpty()){
             minute = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);}
             int second = 0;
             if (!split[2].isEmpty()){
                second  = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);}

              Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();  
              cal.setTime(workDate); 
              cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour); 
              cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);  
              cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);  
              Date newWorkDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: I have upvoted all answers including the question itself, since they all seem to be correct and worth-mentioning uniquely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of hints:

1. Use a `Calendar` object to work with the dates. You can set the `Calendar` from a `Date` so the way you create the dates `textBoxTime` and `workDate` are fine.
2. Set the values of `workDate` from `textBoxTime` using the setXXX methods on `Calendar` class (make `workDate` a `Calendar`)
3. You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to format as well as parse. Use this to produce the desired output.

You should be able to do this with no string parsing and just a few lines of code.

Comment: Just curious, I thought your first two lines were good (using the SimpleDateFormatter to parse -- of course you would need a try/catch to report an error to the user), why didn't you keep them?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the work date, all you need to do is convert your timebox to seconds and add it to your date object.

Use Calendar for date Arithmetic.

```
 Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(date);
 cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
 cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, second);
 Date desiredDate = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need the following code.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date workDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse("2011-11-27");
            Calendar workCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();
            workCalendar.setTime(workDate);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
            time.setTime(simpleDateFormat2.parse("06:00:00"));
            workCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            workCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            workCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, time.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            Date newWorkDate = workCalendar.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            System.out.println(simpleDateFormat3.format(newWorkDate));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Ugggh... That's a lot of parsing that you should let the SimpleDateFormatter handle. See my answer.

Comment: @Ahamed: Thankyou for the detailed code,Ahamed! Very useful.Small note here would be that text box value gives ONLY the HHMMSS value, so there wouldn't be a need for int year, month and date.I can directly set the calendar with the work date and override the time with textbox values using setXXX methods as Francis suggested. :)